# Powershell. How to display the result in a table?

Tags: powershell

Good day.
With Selenium get data:

```
$artist = $ie.FindElementsByXPath("//*[contains(@class, 'album__artist')]")
$title = $ie.FindElementsByXPath("//*[contains(@class, 'album__title')]")
$year = $ie.FindElementsByXPath("//*[contains(@class, 'album__year')]")
$link_artist = $ie.FindElementsByXPath("//*[contains(@class, 'album__artist')]").findelementbytagname("a").GetAttribute("href")
$link_album = $ie.FindElementsByXPath("//*[contains(@class, 'album__title')]").findelementbytagname("a").GetAttribute("href")
```

Everything is issued in a single column. How can you divide the columns? To each variable has a separate column. thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide an example of the output data

Comment: You don't show us a sample of your input data or what you want your output to look like. See [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that you want the results as a single object, rather than in separate variables. If so, you can create a custom object as follows:

```
$AlbumProperties = @{
    artist = $ie.FindElementsByXPath("//*[contains(@class, 'album__artist')]");
    title = $ie.FindElementsByXPath("//*[contains(@class, 'album__title')]");
    year = $ie.FindElementsByXPath("//*[contains(@class, 'album__year')]");
    link_artist = $ie.FindElementsByXPath("//*[contains(@class, 'album__artist')]").findelementbytagname("a").GetAttribute("href");
    link_album = $ie.FindElementsByXPath("//*[contains(@class, 'album__title')]").findelementbytagname("a").GetAttribute("href")
}

$Album = new-object psobject -Property $AlbumProperties
```

Then to display the results as a table:

```
$Album | Format-Table
```

Comment: Mark thanks you! Tell me export this in CSV,TXT with columns possible?

Comment: I need result in column..  Not "one,two,three"

Comment: You can export that single object to a CSV by doing `$Album | Export-CSV filename.csv` and you can export to a .txt file the table view you get from `format-table` by doing `$Album | Format-Table | Out-File filename.txt`.